# WCF Communication in netstandard2.0 (IServiceBehavior and other class which are not supported)

Tags: wcf, .net-core, service, .net-standard-2.0

I have a group of services that are written in WCF. **This is a whole logic which cannot be changed and rewritten to another technology.**

I want to create an application in .NET Core 2.1 and connect to WCF services. I am using library which has clients for all services with custom communication, bindings, endpointbehaviors etc. This library is written in .NET Framework v4.7.2, so if I want to use it in my .NET Core App I need to add target to the .net standard 2.0.

I did this and now I am having a problem as some classes are not supported in .netstandard2.0.

```
public class UserInfoBehavior : Attribute, IServiceBehavior, IEndpointBehavior
{}
```

For Example above class is used for adding EndpointBehaviors to my Channel:

```
public DashboardServiceClient(InstanceContext instanceContext, string endpointConfigurationName, string endpointAddress)
        : base(instanceContext, endpointConfigurationName, endpointAddress)
{
       base.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new UserInfoBehavior());
}
```

The problem is that IServiceBehavior is not available in .netstandard 2.0. Do you know some equivalent for this? There are more classes which I am using and are not supported:

- RemoteEndpointMessageProperty,
- Method Open() which is in ClientBase,
- ChannelDispatcher,
- and also EndpointDispatcher which is empty class in System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher

I am wondering if it is possible to target it to netstandard

Comment: Hi,May I know how is the issue going on now?
If you do not have any other concerns, please remember to mark the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the wcf service by adding a connected reference.
[image]
Select the WCF Web Service Reference Provider.
[image]
Enter your WCF Service URI:
[image]
Check all quotes and finish.
[image]
You can see this folder in the client.

[image]

Just call it in the client, and you can acess the method in WCF Service.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceReference2.Service1Client service1Client = new ServiceReference2.Service1Client();

        var t=service1Client.GetDataAsync(15);
        Console.WriteLine(t.Result); 
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

You can also refer to this link to call the wcf service:
[Use the WCF Web Service Reference Provider Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide)